# Difference between two TTime Variables

Tags: delphi

Looking for a code sample that returns the difference in seconds between two TTime values with positive and negative values. I tried with  SecondsBetween function which is part of the DateUtils unit but it gives only positive value.

Comment: `TTime` has only a fractional part that represents a 24 hour day with values between 0 and 1. A negative sign is ignored. Use a `TDateTime` value if you want a time span greater than a day.

Comment: Note also that [SecondsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) returns a positive number regardless which input value is larger. You will have to handle that by logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signed difference is as simple as this:

```
uses DateUtils, Math;

function TimeDiff(t1, t2: TTime): Integer;
begin
  Result := Sign(t2 - t1) * SecondsBetween(t1, t2);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return the (signed) difference between two TTime values, like if you'd done a T1-T2.

```
USES System.DateUtils;

FUNCTION TimeDifference(T1,T2 : TTime) : INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    Result:=ROUND((FRAC(T1)-FRAC(T2))*SecsPerDay)
  END;
```

Sample code:

```
T1:=EncodeTime(12,0,0,0);
T2:=EncodeTime(13,0,0,0);
WRITELN(TimeDifference(T1,T2));
WRITELN(TimeDifference(T2,T1));
```

Output:

```
-3600
3600
```

Please note, that there's no "negative TTime value". A TTime is always a positive value - the time since midnight on any given day.